# Data Frame That has similar string I want to group all the similar named strings

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy, group-by

```
CardataTransmissions= Cardata.groupby(["Transmission"]).agg(Totalsales=('number', 'sum'))
```

I have grouped the data but it doesn't group all the semi Auto together and its similar.

[image: Output results]

Comment: when you do `group_by` it is sensitive..! hence `Semi auto != Semiauto`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all occurrences of `Semi...` by `Semi Automatic` before grouping:

```
Cartada['Transmission'] = (Cartada['Transmission']
          .str.replace(r'^Semi\s*auto.*', 'Semi Automatic', regex=True))

CardataTransmissions = (Cardata.groupby('Transmission')
                               .agg(Totalsales=('number', 'sum')))
```

Output:

```
>>> CardataTransmissions
     Transmission  Totalsales
0       Automatic         313
1          Manual         621
2  Semi Automatic          66
```

Comment: Thank you, what do you call this function?

Comment: What do you mean? This a search and replace pattern.